# Saving joints to text file - Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

Im trying to store the joint inputs from the Kinect sensor into a text file through a Windows Form Application. Ive tried a few different methods but they dont seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;   
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
namespace kinect
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    KinectSensor KinectSensor = null;
    BodyFrameReader bodyFrameReader = null;
    Body[] bodies = null;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitialiseKinect();
    }

    public void InitialiseKinect()
    {
        KinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
        if (KinectSensor != null)
        {
            //turn on kinect
            KinectSensor.Open();
        }
        bodyFrameReader = KinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

        if (bodyFrameReader != null)
        {
            bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += Reader_FrameArrived;

        }

    }

    private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sensor, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool dataRecieved = false;

        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {

            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                if (bodies == null)
                {
                    bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);
                dataRecieved = true;
            }

            if (dataRecieved)
            {
                foreach (Body body in bodies)
                {
                    if (body.IsTracked)
                    {
                        IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints = body.Joints;
                        Dictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints = new Dictionary<JointType, Point>();

                        //Left points

                        Joint leftShoulder = joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft];

                        float ls_distance_x = leftShoulder.Position.X;
                        float ls_distance_y = leftShoulder.Position.Y;
                        float ls_distance_z = leftShoulder.Position.Z;



                        Joint leftElbow = joints[JointType.ElbowLeft];

                        float le_distance_x = leftElbow.Position.X;
                        float le_distance_y = leftElbow.Position.Y;
                        float le_distance_z = leftElbow.Position.Z;

                        Joint leftwrist = joints[JointType.WristLeft];

                        float lw_distance_x = leftwrist.Position.X;
                        float lw_distance_y = leftwrist.Position.Y;
                        float lw_distance_z = leftwrist.Position.Z;

                        Joint leftHand = joints[JointType.HandLeft];

                        float lh_distance_x = leftHand.Position.X;
                        float lh_distance_y = leftHand.Position.Y;
                        float lh_distance_z = leftHand.Position.Z;


                        Joint tipLeftHand = joints[JointType.HandTipLeft];

                        float lth_distance_x = tipLeftHand.Position.X;
                        float lth_distance_y = tipLeftHand.Position.Y;
                        float lth_distance_z = tipLeftHand.Position.Z;


                        //Right points

                        Joint rightShoulder = joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];

                        float rs_distance_x = rightShoulder.Position.X;
                        float rs_distance_y = rightShoulder.Position.Y;
                        float rs_distance_z = rightShoulder.Position.Z;

                        Joint rightElbow = joints[JointType.ElbowRight];

                        float re_distance_x = rightElbow.Position.X;
                        float re_distance_y = rightElbow.Position.Y;
                        float re_distance_z = rightElbow.Position.Z;

                        Joint rightWrist = joints[JointType.WristRight];

                        float rw_distance_x = rightWrist.Position.X;
                        float rw_distance_y = rightWrist.Position.Y;
                        float rw_distance_z = rightWrist.Position.Z;

                        Joint rightHand = joints[JointType.HandRight];

                        float rh_distance_x = rightHand.Position.X;
                        float rh_distance_y = rightHand.Position.Y;
                        float rh_distance_z = rightHand.Position.Z;


                        Joint tipRightHand = joints[JointType.HandTipRight];

                        float rth_distance_x = tipRightHand.Position.X;
                        float rth_distance_y = tipRightHand.Position.Y;
                        float rth_distance_z = tipRightHand.Position.Z;
                        float rth_distance_n = tipRightHand.Position.N;



                    }
                }
            }


        }


    }



}
```

}